# Nginx HTTP to HTTPS redirect loop

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have the folloiwng Nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name .example.net .example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name beta.example.com;

        error_page 403 /403;
        error_page 404 /404;
        error_page 500 /500;

        client_max_body_size 5M;

        # Handle all locations
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/csr.pem;

        server_name example.com;

        error_page 403 /403;
        error_page 404 /404;
        error_page 500 /500;

        client_max_body_size 5M;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

I'm wanting to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS however I get a redirect loop. I've read other answers on different questions including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389064/nginx-redirect-to-https-redirect-loop) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302070/nginx-http-to-https-redirection-issue) however none of their solutions solved mine. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your backend (running on 127.0.0.1:8000) issues `Location: http://example.com/` header.

Please look into the access logs, nginx's and backend's too.

Or use `httpliveheaders` or `tcpdump` to investigate the traffic.